# how to add dynamic colors to the map component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react echarts for my data visualization to show the counties of a state map.
I need to update each county with different color defaultly.
Currently all the counties in the map are shown with same color. How to update different colors to different counties in a way that neither 2 neighbouring counties should have same color

``

```
const EVENT_SELECT = 'select'
const EVENT_UNSELECT = 'unselect'
const EVENT_CLICK = 'click'

const usCountyDta = geoJson
const wdaCounties = geoWDAJson

type MapProps = {
  state: string
  stateId: string
  countyId: string
  mapColor?: string
  mapHoverColor?: string
}

export function MapLink(props: MapProps) {
  const option = {
    textStyle: {
      fontFamily: '"Roboto","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif',
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'item',
      formatter: (params: any) => {
        const wda = wdaCounties.wdas.filter((item) => item.counties.includes(params.name))
        const counties = wda[0].wda
        return counties
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Selected',
        type: 'map',
        map: 'Texas',
        nameProperty: 'NAME',
        selectedMode: 'multiple',
        right: '10px',
        label: {
          show: false,
        },
  
        emphasis: {
          label: {
            show: false,
          },
          itemStyle: {
            areaColor: props.mapHoverColor||'#EADDCA',
          },
        },
        itemStyle: {
          areaColor: props.mapColor||'#5f8f2c',
        },
        select: {
          label: {
            show: false,
          },
          itemStyle: {
            areaColor: props.mapHoverColor||'#EADDCA',
          },
        },
        data: [],
      },
    ],
  }
  const mapRef = useRef<EChartsInstance | null>(null)
  const [mapOptions] = useState({
    ...option,
    series: [
      {
        ...option.series[0],
        map: props.state,
      },
    ],
  })

  const texasCountyData = {
    type: usCountyDta.type,
    features: usCountyDta.features.filter((feature) => feature.properties.STATE === props.stateId),
  }

  // @ts-ignore
  echarts.registerMap(props.state, texasCountyData)

  const updateMap = (map: EChartsInstance, selection: string[]) => {
    try {
      map.dispatchAction({
        type: EVENT_UNSELECT,
        name: texasCountyData.features.map((feature) => feature.properties.NAME),
      })

      map.dispatchAction({
        type: EVENT_SELECT,
        name: selection,
      })
    } catch { }
  }
```

``